# How to send an XML request in URL and get XML response back

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to use jQuery Ajax to post an XML request and get XML response back. 
I have to hit this below URL to post request and get an XML response back.

**Request**

```
var xml_response=http://test.test.in:8080/RestAPI/ServiceRequestServlet?request=<xml><request><functiontype>2003</functiontype><groupzid>185</groupzid><moduleid>8</moduleid><servicetype>21</servicetype></request></xml>
```

**Response**

```
<xml>
<response>
<servicetype>21</servicetype>
<functiontype>2003</functiontype>
<statuscode>0</statuscode>
<statusmessage>Success</statusmessage>
<groupzid>185</groupzid>
<servicerequestcategories>
<element>
<category>dtdc courier</category>
</element>
<element>
<category>gardening</category>
</element>
<element>
<category>plumber</category>
</element>
<element>
<category>Electrician</category>
</element>
<element>
<category>Others</category>
</element>
</servicerequestcategories>
</response>
</xml>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dvContent").append("<ul></ul>");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: xml_response,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
    $(xml).find('Response').each(function(){
      var sr_category = $(this).find('servicerequestcategories').text();
      var category = $(this).find('category').text();

    });
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
  }
  });
});
```

When I try to give this I'm not getting response and it says XML process error.

Comment: look in browser console network tab and provide more details. Is this a different domain, subdomain or port than the page is on?

Comment: @charlietfl I doubt for the URL created for request. Is it correct way for passing URL as request